# Parsing stray text with Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Any idea how to extract 'TEXT TO GRAB' from this piece of markup:

```
<span class="navigation_page">
    <span>
        <a itemprop="url" href="http://www.example.com">
            <span itemprop="title">LINK</span>
        </a>
    </span>
    <span class="navigation-pipe">&gt;</span>
    TEXT TO GRAB
</span>
```

Comment: Try response.css(‘span.navigation_page::text’).extract_first()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an ideal solution but it should do the trick:

```
from scrapy import Selector

content="""
<span class="navigation_page">
    <span>
        <a itemprop="url" href="http://www.example.com">
            <span itemprop="title">LINK</span>
        </a>
    </span>
    <span class="navigation-pipe">&gt;</span>
    TEXT TO GRAB
</span>
"""
sel = Selector(text=content)
item = sel.css(".navigation_page::text")
print(item.extract()[-1].strip())
```

OR like this:

```
sel = Selector(text=content)
item = ''.join([' '.join(items.split()) for items in sel.css("span.navigation_page::text").extract()])
print(item)
```

Output:

```
TEXT TO GRAB
```

Answer (score 2):

Not ideal:

```
text_to_grab = response.xpath('//span[@class="navigation-pipe"]/following-sibling::text()[1]').extract_first()
```